# How to handle async file upload in uploadify?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, uploadify

I have a uploadify plugin on my page and below it I have a description field and a textbox for it. I have submit button below it. Now my problem is uploadify will start async file upload as soon as you select file. I want the uploadify to start upload on click of submit button and also description field's value to be available on the server. I am aware that there is option where you can ask uploadify to start upload on the click of some button. But even if I do that the submit button click event will be fired and the upload will be lost. Should I use script manager and update panel (uploadify should not be inside update panel) so that when submit button click event is fired the page doesn't reset and the uploadify can continue its work. How do you all typically handle this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable auto start of the file upload, add this setting to the config of the uploadify:

```
'auto'      : false
```

To submit the values of the form to the server along with file you need to create a separate link or button that gets the data from the form and send it using the uploadifySettings function and then call uploadifyUpload().

Here is an example that will send the details of an MP3 file filled in a form by user.

```
<a onclick="$('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'artist':$('#t_artist').val(), 'album':$('#t_album').val() }); $('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload()" class="greenBtn">START UPLOAD</a>
```

Where #t_artist and $t_album are the IDs of the input fields in the form.